# Acumatica - How to Access a Protected Class Declared in the Base Graph of a Graph Extension

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a graph extension of the `INPIReview` graph in Acumatica (version 20.118.0007). I need to override the protected method `UpdateCreditLinesCost` to prevent an exception from being thrown. The problem is that this method returns `IEnumerable<ProjectedTranRec>`, and `ProjectedTranRec` is a protected class that is declared in the parent class (`INPIEntry`) of `INPIReview`. This means that I can't use the class in the graph extension, and, therefore, I can't use the same method signature to override the method in the base graph.

I attempted to use the `PXProtectedAccessAttribute` on an abstract class with the same signature of the `ProjectedTranRec` class in my graph extension. The problem with that is that the overriding method signature is not the same as the base graph method signature because of the different `ProjectedTranRec`'s.

Is there a way to access a protected class that is declared in a base graph from a graph extension and use that class to override a method in the base graph that uses that class?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exception you are trying to prevent? Another means may be available than trying to access a protected class.

Comment: I know doesn't help your situation directly but looks like ProjectedTranRec was changed to public starting in 21R2